# CS0117 WebMatrix.Data.Database does not contain a definition to 'open'

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I am a beginner with webmatrix and have stared with ASP.Net Razor Pages Getting started. Successfully completed first 4 lessons. Now I am on lesson 5 working with data. Database is created, tabke Product also created and updated. Listproducts.cshtml matches each and every character as per the code on the tutorial pages. 
However when I run this file I get an error --CS0117 WebMatrix.Data.Database does not contain a definition to 'open',I am stuck her for last  3 days.
Appreiciate help from all 
Vinod

Answer (score 4):

The method should be "Open", not "open". (casing difference)